# How do I remap Alt+` (key above Tab) in GNOME 3.36.2 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 20.04

I am trying to change the key to summon my Guake Terminal to <kbd>Alt+</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (backtick, the key above <kbd>Tab</kbd>) and only to find out that the key is occupied by GNOME for cycling through windows of the active application.

When I go into the keyboard shortcut settings I found that the exact same feature was displayed to be mapped to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> and both key combos behaves the same.

But since the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> was not "assigned" to anything in settings, I cannot change it. Is there any command-line method that I can use to make GNOME not intercepting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> key combo via *dconf Editor* or `gsettings`

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group
```

Example:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group
['<Super>Above_Tab', '<Alt>Above_Tab']
```

By running below command, you are removing `'<Alt>Above_Tab'` key-combo

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-group "['<Super>Above_Tab']"
```

Now you can assign any command to this key-combo via keyboard shortcut settings.

[image]

dconf-editor is not installed by default.. If you wish to change via GUI

install dconf-editor

```
sudo apt install dconf-editor
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That perfectly solved my problem. I just switched from windows and there are a lot of stuff I need to learn. Is there any particular reason that ```Alt+` ``` was not made easily configurable in settings?

Comment: Hi.. not only that combo.. it is related to keyboard shortcut functionality.. if the key combo is already assigned and when you hit that combo in shortcut keys.. it will bring the command in action. so first you need to deactivate that combo. it applys to all. not particularly for Alt back tick..